# Swift OptionSetType Bitwise-Or

Tags: swift, bitwise-or, optionsettype

Say I have the following `OptionSetType`

```
struct Modifier : OptionSetType {

    typealias RawValue = Int
    var rawValue: RawValue = 0

    static let Default: Modifier = [.Public, .Package, .Internal]

    static let Public    = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let Package   = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let Protected = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let Internal  = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let Private   = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 4)

    static let Static    = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 5) 
    static let Final     = Modifier(rawValue: 1 << 6) 

    init(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

}
```

How would I determine whether or not a value of type `Modifier` contains at least one of the elements contained in `Modifier.Default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
let modifier: Modifier = ...

if Modifier.Default.contains(modifier) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let m = Modifier()
m.contains([.Public]) // false

let m1 = Modifier.Default
m1.contains([.Public, .Package, .Internal]) // true
m1.contains([.Public])                      // true
// ....
```